How to customize the viewer for files in Autodesk-construction-cloud
When I click on a file in Docs or Build within Autodesk Construction Cloud, the file is displayed on the web (viewer).
https://help.autodesk.com/view/DOCS/ENU/?guid=View_Navigation_Toolbars
I want to customize this viewer.
However, I couldn't find a way to customize it using the APS viewer API.
Is it not possible to customize it?
If customization is not possible, I think I will have to create my own web page and use the viewer API there.
In that case, when I click on a file in ACC, I need it to jump to my own website instead of the above viewer.
I understand that this is impossible.
(This text is machine translated.)

Unfortunately, the viewer on Autodesk Construction Cloud cannot be customized.
Instead, you can make your own viewer application using APS Viewer to view models stored in Docs or Build within Autodesk Construction Cloud. Please refer to our Hub viewer tutorial: https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/hubs-browser/
let modelUrn = 'urn: dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5maWxlOnZmLlNrbjlTSkk4UVVpUkwwZHBtN29jNVE_dmVyc2lvbj0x';
Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(modelUrn, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);

function onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc) {
    let defaultView = doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
    viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, defaultView);
}

function onDocumentLoadFailure() {
    console.error('Failed fetching model manifest');
}

With this, you can also do the viewer customization for example:

https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics/toolbar-button/
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics/extensions/
https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/dashboard/charts

